# Defining optional parameters in \newcommand

Tags: optional-arguments

If I have a command in the form

```
\newcommand{\TM}[1]{\color{red} $\boldsymbol{#1}$}
```

how can I call it with an optional parameter for color? What I want is that if it's called like

```
\TM{\alpha}
```

it should return a red alpha but if it's called as

```
\TM[green]{\alpha}
```

the alpha's color should be green.

Comment: Well, this is very well-known: `\newcommand{\TM}[2][red]{{\color{#1}$#2$}}` (or, better, `\newcommand*{\TM}[2][red]{{\color{#1}$#2$}}`).  Note the additional pair of braces (this is unrelated to your question, though)!

Comment: @Gustavo Could you explian what is "unrelated" to the question? It is unclear to me, as Latex remains often unclear doing the job well.

Comment: The extra pair of curly brackets will stop the rest of your document turning red. But this is unrelated to your question.

Answer (score 13):

An optional parameter is defined by adding a `[<opt>]` after defining the number of arguments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,amsmath}

\newcommand{\TM}[2][red]{\textcolor{#1}{$\boldsymbol{#2}$}}

\begin{document}

\TM{\alpha}

\TM[green!50!black]{\beta}

\end{document}
```

Note that it's not always a good idea to include math formatting within a command, since it will cause errors if used inside math. For this, LaTeX provides `\ensuremath`.

To circumvent this, I've used `\textcolor{<colour>}{<stuff>}` which necessarily puts `<stuff>` in text mode. As such, a switch to math mode would be okay.

Comment: `\textcolor` doesn't actually force text mode (blame the author of the color package;-)