# Unable calculate value of coordinate by macro constructed by \newcommand in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex-core

I construct a macro named `\mycal`(with an optional argument) to calculate value of coordinates which will be used in `\tikz\draw`.
I find that with this optioal arg, the code can not compile. When the optional arg become mandatory, the code works all right. But I do need this arg optional.
Why and how to solve this problem?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,picture}

\begin{document}
% The following part can not compile
% \newcommand{\mycal}[3][0pt]{\the\dimexpr #2 + #3 + #1}
% \newcommand\mydraw[3]{\tikz\draw(0,0)--(\mycal[#1]{#2}{#3},0);}
% \mydraw{1pt}{2cm}{3cm}

% The following part ok!
\newcommand{\mycal}[3]{\the\dimexpr #2 + #3 + #1}
\newcommand\mydraw[3]{\tikz\draw(0,0)--(\mycal{#1}{#2}{#3},0);}
\mydraw{1pt}{2cm}{3cm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does [this tip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/357918/146828) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1812224/8854526) help ?

Comment: What confuses me is why macro with optional arg can not be used in tikz coordinate calculation and how to solve it if optional arg has to be kept in macro defination.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your macro does not work because macros with optional arguments are not expandable and therefore cannot be used in the middle of a path construction. Tex has to perform some assignment to determine whether the optional argument is present or not. The solution may be to use `\pgfextra` which allows you to interrupt temporarily the construction of the path and execute some code. You have to modify your code to save the result of the computation to some register and then use it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newdimen\mydimen
\newcommand\mycal[3][0cm]{\mydimen=\dimexpr #2 + #3 + #1\relax}
\newcommand\mydraw[3][0cm]{\tikz\draw(0cm,0cm) \pgfextra{\mycal[#1]{#2}{#3}} --(\mydimen,0cm);}

\begin{document}
\mydraw[1cm]{2cm}{3cm}

\mydraw{2cm}{3cm}
\end{document}
```

By the way, in your example, `\mycal` does not really need to take an optional argument. `\mydraw` does.

```
\newcommand\mycal[3]{\dimexpr #2 + #3 + #1\relax}
\newcommand\mydraw[3][0cm]{\begin{tikzpicture}\draw(0cm,0cm)-- (\mycal{#1}{#2}{#3},0cm);
```

EDIT:

If you really insist on using `\mycal` with an optional argument without using `\pgfextra`, you can use the following trick. It defines an expandable `\mycalc` with an optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\mycal#1{%
  \ifx[#1\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {\@mycal[}{\@mycal[0cm]{#1}}}
\def\@mycal[#1]#2#3{\dimexpr#1+#2+#3\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tikz\draw(0cm,0cm)--(\mycal{2cm}{3cm},0cm);

\tikz\draw(0cm,0cm)--(\mycal[1cm]{2cm}{3cm},0cm);
\end{document}
```

NEW EDIT:

To write `\mycal{2cm,3cm}` or `\mycal[1cm]{2cm,3cm}` instead of `\mycal{2cm}{3cm}` or `\mycal[1cm]{2cm}{3cm}` you can define `\mycal` as follows

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\mycal#1{%
  \ifx[#1\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {\@mycal[}{\@mycal[0cm]{#1}}}
\def\@mycal[#1]#2{\@@mycal{#1}#2\@nil}
\def\@@mycal#1#2,#3\@nil{\dimexpr#1+#2+#3\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tikz\draw(0cm,0cm)--(\mycal{2cm,3cm},0cm);

\tikz\draw(0cm,0cm)--(\mycal[1cm]{2cm,3cm},0cm);
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Eric. Optional args is needed in \mycal, because there are many calculations in the path, and for most of them ,#1 is 0cm. So I don't want to write so many "[...]" which is only 0cm and does not affect the result of calculation. Is there any other way to force expland of optional args？

Comment: @lyl I updated my answer to define an expandable macro `\mycal` with an optional argument.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solutions. And is there a way to construct \mycal when calling it like this: \mycal{1cm,2cm} rather than \mycal{1cm}{2cm}?

Comment: @lyl I updated again my answer.

Comment: Many many thanks!! Please forgive my greed. I think a macro like "\mycal[5pt]{1pt,2pt,3em,4cm,...,5mm} "(the mandatory arg is a list dilimited by ",", the number of the list member is variable ) will be the ultimate solution. Is there such a solution?

Comment: @lyl It is possible to achieve this but if you want an arbritrary number of arguments, what is the point of having an optional one?

Comment: @lyl Also, if you can give the mandatory argument under the form `{1pt,2pt,3em,4cm,...,5mm}` why not simply `{1pt+2pt+3em+4cm+...+5mm}`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89323/discussion-between-lyl-and-eric-domenjoud).